# Fix width label with form controls inside

Tags: css

There're many ways to accomplish fix-width labels when the corresponding form control is in some other node:

```
<label for="foo">Text</label>
<input id="foo">
```

However, I've been struggling to find a sensible way to do it when form control is *inside* the label:

```
<label>Text <input></label>
```

My best attempts imply taking form controls out of page flow thus break with items that have a different height, e.g.:

```css
label{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 9em;
  background-color: azure;
}
input, textarea{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 11em;
  width: 15em;
}
textarea{
  height: 8em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Short <textarea></textarea></label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>This is a very long label text <input></label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Average sized <input></label>
</div>
```

Given this HTML markup, is there any other reasonably simple CSS-only technique that expands vertically as needed, both for label and control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you actually want it to look.

Using flex comes to mind.

Here is a simple test:

```css
label{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width:23em;
  background-color: azure;
}

input, textarea{
  font:inherit;
  width: 15em;
  margin-left:auto;
  flex:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

textarea{
  height: 8em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Short <textarea></textarea></label>
</div>

<div>
  <label>This is a very long label text <input></label>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Average sized <input></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. its pretty much compatible with all browsers across the board

```css
label{
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px ;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: azure;
}
label > span {
  width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
label > input, textarea{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
}
textarea{
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label><span>Short</span> <textarea></textarea></label>
</div>
<div>
  <label><span>This is a very long label text</span> <input></label>
</div>
<div>
  <label><span>Average sized </span><input></label>
</div>
```